# White space around dialog box | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, android-alertdialog, padding

i am trying to make an otp verification dialog in flutter but it keeps adding padding/ white space around the actual widget and I don't know how to remove it.
I've tried making the inset padding zero and content padding zero but it just changes the size of dialog box and does nothing with the difference in widget and dialog box.
Here's my code:

```
      return AlertDialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),

    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    content: Container(
      height: 244,
      width: 380,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 30),
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 30,
              child : Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 66,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Verification",
                            // textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                fontSize: 20,

                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: Color(0xff4D4D4D)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 6,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: Text(
                              "We have just sent your phone an OTP, please enter below to verify",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  fontSize: 7,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: Color(0xff4D4D4D)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 33,
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/smartphone_verification.png",scale:5,))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // SizedBox(height: 100,),
            // SizedBox(height: 50,),
            Container(
              width: 331,
              height: 41,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){},
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF0E3C6E)),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                          RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            // side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                          ))),

                  child: Text("Verify")),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyFVQ.jpg)
while it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bey1C.png)

Comment: remove `Card` widget , and also padding on the `Container`

Answer (score 0):

this padding you talk about come from this line:

> padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 30),

in first container, and also put card elevation to 0.

Comment: @ABV was it what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The card widget has got elevation and padding too. Please remove the card widget and add

```
mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated few things in code. Below is the updated source. I had to comment style to make it running. Please enable it in your sample.

```
AlertDialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                    content: Container(
                      height: 170,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 6,
                                    child: Column(

                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "Verification",
                                          // textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          /* style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                          fontSize: 20,

                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                          color: Color(0xff4D4D4D)),*/
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 6,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 8),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "We have just sent your phone an OTP, please enter below to verify",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            /*   style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                            fontSize: 7,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Color(0xff4D4D4D)),*/
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 3,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/images/smartphone_verification.png",
                                      scale: 5,
                                    ))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          // SizedBox(height: 100,),
                          // SizedBox(height: 50,),
                          Container(
                            height: 41,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        Color(0xFF0E3C6E)),
                                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                            RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                                      // side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                    ))),
                                child: Text("Verify")),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

It will look like this.

[image]